# Embedded vs Non-Embedded Java Server

Tags: java, tomcat, heroku, webserver

I'm working on a Java project and have been using a Tomcat server for local testing. However I am about to push up to Heroku and I found [an article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat) that suggests to use "embedded" Tomcat.

I looked around to see what exactly "embedded" meant in the context of a Java server but it seems like everyone on Google already understands what "embedded" means. I don't. What is the difference between deploying a "regular" Tomcat server and an "embedded" one?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

"Embedded" means that you program ships with the server within it as opposed to a web application being deployed to external server.

With embedded server your application is packaged with the server of choice and responsible for server start-up and management.

From the user standpoint the difference is:

- Application with embedded server looks like a regular java program. You just launch it and that's it.
- Regular web application is usually a `war` archive which needs to be deployed to some server

Embedding a server is very useful for testing purposes where you can start or stop server at will during the test.

Comment: is the tomcat version reflected in tomcat embedded are the same as actual tomcat ? i.e. lets say if the tomcat available for download on Apache site is of version 8.5 and tomcat embedded (as shown in this link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.5) are same or different?

Answer (score 10):

Traditionally, to host Java web applications, you installed a single Tomcat instance on your server, and pushed all of your WAR files onto that one server. Maybe you clustered a few Tomcat instances together, but the idea is the same. There was one Tomcat server, and all of your Java web apps were deployed to it.

**Traditional vs Embedded Tomcat**

In the world of microservices, things are a little different. Instead of one Tomcat server hosting many web applications, with microservices, we take the one web application, deploy that one web application to a one tomcat server, and then zip it all up in a zip, jar or war file that is executable through the Java command. So now we have a single executable file that contains everything you need to run the web app, including the Tomcat server.

**Container Based Distribution**

Some products ship their entire product in an [embedded servlet engine](https://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/How-to-embed-Tomcat-and-Java-web-apps-in-an-executable-JAR). You can get [Jenkins](https://www.theserverside.com/video/Step-by-step-Jenkins-Tomcat-deploy-of-a-WAR-file) in a single executable WAR file, although I believe they embed Jetty, not Tomcat, but it's the same idea. But less likely than distributing the jar/war, what people do is package the whole thing up in a docker container and deploy it all to Kubernetes or Heruku or whatever.

So that's kinda the idea behind an [embedded tomcat server](https://www.theserverside.com/definition/embedded-Tomcat).

**Maven and Embedded Tomcat**

One of the easiest way to create an embedded tomcat server is with [Apache Maven](https://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/How-to-install-Maven-and-build-apps-with-the-mvn-command-line). Here's an example of a Maven build that not only builds a web app, but also downloads tomcat and packages the whole thing in an executable JAR:

[image: Embedded Tomcat with Maven]

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20020416124014/http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/04/03/tomcat.html), it's when you "embed" tomcat into your application. That is, you are responsible for starting and stopping tomcat. This is the reverse of a normal container operation, but you might find it useful for rapid deployment and testing.